# Single stock for 2 products Woo Commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

We are using tickera with woocommerce that used to build an event ticket webshop.

There are a couple of different types of tickets. Early bird VIP, Early bird, regular,... All of them have their own stock. So for Early bird VIP, it will be 100 tickets. early bird will be 300 and regular will be 1000 for example. This all works perfectly and the last year they have been using this without a problem. Now comes the big issue. They introduced Memberships (I am using woo commerce memberships) to handle this so they can buy cheaper merch and tickets. The stock keeping with the membership goes like this: for Early bird VIP it will be 100 tickets. early bird will be 300 and REGULAR & MEMBER tickets will share the same stock of 1000 tickets. So I created 2 products 1 member product and 1 regular product to make sure it is clear on the ticket what type of ticket the user bought. But this fucked the complete stock keeping. Because 2 woocommerce products can not have the same stocks. I can not figure out how I should do this.

Comment: Sorry, but without any code, logs or complete knowledge about your system I can't help you. Also, I would suggest reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to improve your question because it sounds more like an angry statement instead of a question with helpful details to find a solution....

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to tickera, They told me to use 1 product with 2 variations.

- regular
- member

The variation type will be added to the pdf export & ticket itself so it is clear what type of ticket was bought.

In combination with the variations setup you could also use `Shared Variation Inventory` plugin from the woo-commerce website itself. It makes it easy to sell in bulk.